# how to fix "error C2872: 'IDictionary' :ambiguous symbol[ VS2012 - C++/CLI]

Tags: c++-cli

I need to use IDictionary in my project. When I add this compiler does not like it and report an obvious error 
“error C2872: 'IDictionary' : ambiguous symbol” . However if I create a new                  sample project compiler never reports any error

```
  Below is the code snippet
 Temp.h
#pragma once
#using "System.dll"

using namespace::System;
using namespace::System::Collections;
using namespace::System::Collections::Specialized;

public ref class MyCollection : public NameObjectCollectionBase {

private:
DictionaryEntry^ _de;

// Gets a key-and-value pair (DictionaryEntry) using an index. 
public:
property DictionaryEntry^ default[ int ] {
      DictionaryEntry^ get(int index) {
     _de->Key = this->BaseGetKey( index );
      _de->Value = this->BaseGet( index );
      return( _de );
    }
  }

  // Adds elements from an IDictionary into the new collection.
   MyCollection( IDictionary^ d ) {

   _de = gcnew DictionaryEntry();

  for each ( DictionaryEntry^ de in d ) {
    this->BaseAdd( (String^) de->Key, de->Value );
      }
  }

   // Removes an entry with the specified key from the collection. 
   void Remove( String^ key ) {
    this->BaseRemove( key );
  }

   // Removes an entry in the specified index from the collection. 
   void Remove( int index ) {
  this->BaseRemoveAt( index );
   } 
  };
```

Comment: Putting `using namespace` directives in a .h file is dangerous, especially when you use such an obsolete .NET 1.x namespace.  You'll #include the file in another source file that uses the generic version of IDictionary and the compiler can no longer figure out which one you want.  Just don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your application has more that one `IDictionary` interface in different namespaces you'll have to fully qualify the reference.  For example:

```
System::Collections::IDictionary^ d
```

Or whatever the namespace of the other `IDictionary` type is.

Alternatively you could remove the `using` statements for one of the namespace's.

Comment: Yeah, If I mention the path explicitly, I do not get the error.